# editor component like RichEdit that supports embedding photos?

Tags: delphi, richedit

can anyone suggest an editor component like RichEdit that supports embedding photos in a delphi app?  RichEdit doesn't seem to support this.

am not considering embedding MS Word since not everyone would have that.

than you for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recomend TRichView http://www.trichview.com/.

I did work with WPTools for long time, but recently I found TRichView a lot more simple to use.

Comment: +1 - tRichView works very well, and you can continue to use the RTF file format if you so desire for added flexibility.

Comment: thank you--that sounds like a great way to go!

Answer (score 1):

AFAIR the TrxRichEdit from rxlib supported embedding pictures. Since rxlib was incorporated into the jvcl, I guess TJvRichEdit should as well.

Comment: interesting--i just tried it & it actually works!  next i'd need to figure out how to serialize that so i can save it in a database.  thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think it should work when you insert bmp files. Other image files are not supported. Maybe you can convert your images to a bitmap first?

Comment: thank you for your suggestion.  i never did figure out how to do that except maybe with inserting objects.  in our case we need something more powerful.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind paying for a component library, I recommend [WP Tools](http://www.wpcubed.com/products/wptools/index.htm). They have extensive support for document formatting (including inserting images) and provide their library as native VCL package (so you don't have the "what version of Word" conversation).

Comment: i don't mind at all; 3rd party components are generally an excellent solution for situations like this.  thank you for your comment.  the "what version of Word" conversation is definitely a conversation i don't want to have!